# Correct value of time spent in website visit

Tags: .net, firefox, microsoft-edge, browser-history

I need time spent by user on his websites visited on his machine. the solution used does not give correct results for Firefox and Edge browsers. Which columns OR tables should I query to have accurate time spent by user? Used approach from [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3e9f3588-ad0b-49af-b269-2abfda0b9abc/how-to-get-the-browser-history-in-program-using-c?forum=csharpgeneral)

The 2 tables give following columns, nothing about time spent:

[image]

[image: 2nd Table is below]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the data obtained is a timestamp, in the **last_visit_date column**. When you remove the last three zeros from the data in the column, it will be a valid timestamp (in milliseconds). You can calculate the duration from the difference between them.

For example: 1623664584602 -> 1623664654008

(GMT): 2021-06-14 9:56:24 -> (GMT): 2021-06-14 9:57:34 => takes one minute and ten seconds

In .NET, you could try to calculate the specific time through this:

```
DateTime _dtStart = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime getTime = _dtStart.AddMilliseconds(timeStamp);
```